# How to target non-unique, dynamically generated elements in the DOM with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener, dynamically-generated

I have an `input` field that pushes the inputted string into an array, then generates a `<li>` from each object in the array.  I also have a click listener added to each list item as it is generated.

The click listener and the dynamically generated list items work as expected, except the only thing I can get the click listener's function to do is console.log, because I don't know how to target the list item that has just been clicked.

I want to target the clicked item to add a `class` that will change it's `text-decoration` to `line-through`.  I have everything in place, I just need to figure out how to target the clicked item using the DOM.

I have tried `document.querySelectorAll("li")`, but that only returns a Nodelist.  I have tried every other DOM method I can think of as well, I have tried passing `this` as an argument in the function when it is called.  There is no way to make each generated list item unique, they all have the same class and the same parent.

If I target the first child by saying `document.getElementByTagName("ul").firstChild.classList.add("strikethrough");` everything works, meaning the code is bug free, but that won't work when I have 10 list items and the 4th item is clicked.

I want to include my entire code, but I don't want to confuse the question, because there are many things going on from line to line, and each function is handling multiple processes.  Again, I want to reiterate that everything works, I just am missing the final link, which is how to target this non-unique, dynamically generated element that has just been clicked on with DOM (or similar).

Here's the snippet in question, it should have everything you need to know about the code:

```
let plannerItems = [];
let backwardsArray = plannerItems.reverse();

function createList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < backwardsArray.length; i++) {
    var plannerItem = backwardsArray[i];
    var nextItem = document.createElement("li");
    nextItem.innerHTML= plannerItem;
    nextItem.classList.add("listItems");
    nextItem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      crossOff();
    });
    document.getElementById("list").prepend(nextItem);
  };
};

function crossOff() {
  document.getElementById("list").firstChild.classList.add("strikethrough");
   ////This is where I would put my DOM method....If I had one... ////
};
```

So, as you can see the very last line of code above the comment is the one I need to replace with the correct DOM method.  I have also tried `nextItem.classlist.add("strikethrough");` but that only adds the class to the first child, and not the clicked text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the element the element that was clicked upon from event using [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).`currentTarget`, you could pass this into `crossOff()`:

```js
let plannerItems = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten'];
let backwardsArray = plannerItems.reverse();

function createList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < backwardsArray.length; i++) {
    var plannerItem = backwardsArray[i];
    var nextItem = document.createElement("li");
    nextItem.innerHTML= plannerItem;
    nextItem.classList.add("listItems");
    nextItem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      crossOff(event.currentTarget);
    });
    document.getElementById("list").prepend(nextItem);
  };
};

function crossOff(item) {
  item.classList.add("strikethrough");
};

createList();
```

```css
.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

li {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: That is excellent, and indeed it works, thank you so much.  Trying to make sure I understand this implicitly.... so the `(item)` you pass in the function declaration is the same as `(event.currentTarget)` argument during the function call?  I was trying to use `(this)` to no avail.  Is this the kind of things that is covered in the `addEventListener` documentation from mdn or w3?

Comment: [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) would work too as long as it is in context, and yes you can find almost everything in mdn, [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler)